# Is 摆有 one word or two? If two, what's their grammatical relationship?

Tags: meaning, mandarin, vocabulary, word

> 桌上摆有一卷书

(source: example sentence in a publicly available flashcard deck - no other context provided).

None of the 40+ dictionaries I consulted carry this lemma, and google offers precious little too.

I would have used 摆着 (or 放着) in that context; is 有 a typo for 着 or is 摆有 (and perhaps 放有) a legitimate word? If so, is it dialectal? Can you think of any other such -有 constructions, aside from normal dictionary words like 拥有, 持有, etc. ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

According to 現代漢語八百詞 (p.630), 有 (which means “possess”) is a verb that can follow a monosyllabic verb to form a tightly-bound term. In linguistic terms, it is called a **serial verb compound**.

桌上有一卷书 (there is a book on the table)

桌上摆有一卷书 (there is a book placed on the table) - *摆 explains how the book is situated on the table -- it laid/ sits there*

More example:

庭中有几棵树 (There are several trees in the courtyard)

庭中种有几棵树 (There are several trees planted in the courtyard) - *種 explains how the trees are situated in the courtyard -- they grow there*

車上有四人 (There are four people in the car)

車上坐有四人 (There are four people sitting in the car)

屋中有一百袋大米 (There are a hundred bags of rice in the house)

屋中堆有一百袋大米 (There are a hundred bags of rice piled up in the house)

手中有一把七尺長刀 (Have a seven-foot-long knife in hand)

手中持有一把七尺長刀 (Have a seven-foot-long knife holding in hand)

Different verbs can work with 有 in the above sentences. e.g. 庭中横放有几棵树, 车上躺有四人, 屋中藏有一百袋大米; 手中握有一把七尺长刀

Comment: If `車上有四人 -> 車上**坐**有四人` and `四人在車上 -> 四人**坐**在車上 `, do you think it would it be correct to regard 有 as syntactically comparable to 在, from a strictly grammatical point of view? I find it enlightening to see 有 behave like what's variously described as a co-verb or light verb, i.e. a weak/base verb that can be liberally qualified by another _independent_ verb to become a complex predicate.

Comment: @Sanchuan Quote: *"regard 有 as syntactically comparable to 在"* 車上坐有四人 = 有四人坐在車上. The relationship  between 有 (there are) and 坐 (sit)  doesn't seem similar to 坐 and 在 where 坐 is verb and 在 is a preposition;

Comment: Their behaviour does seem awfully similar though: `在+车上, (坐)有+四人` = `有+四人, (坐)在+车上`. We probably shouldn't rush to force 在 into a different grammatical category just because it's mostly translated as a preposition in _English_.

Comment: @Sanchuan I think 車上坐有四人 look similar to 車上坐著四人, but they are syntactically different  -- 有 indicates the existence of the object; 著 indicates the continuous  state of the verb

Answer (score 0):

摆有 is not a single word but rather a simple construct of two separate words 摆 and 有.

It be could argued that a case could be made to treat it as a single word, but this distinction doesn't really make much of a difference semantically.

Your question indicates that you already have a fairly good handle of the way the grammar works. For instance, 放有, like you mentioned also works in a similar way to 摆有.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've come to think much the same, though I'm still at a loss as to how to think of this kind of loose V+有 pairings from a grammatical point of view. They don't behave like your typical "serial verb construction" (if that category is of any use in the first place...).